# T-SQL Format integer to 2-digit string

Tags: t-sql, format, casting

I can't find a simple way to do this in T-SQL.

I have for example a column (SortExport_CSV) that returns an integer '2' thru 90.
If the stored number is a single digit, I need it to convert to a 2 digit string that begins with a 0.
I have tried to use CAST but I get stuck on how to display the style in the preferred format (0#)

Of course it is easy to do this on the front end (SSRS, MSAccess, Excel, etc) but in this instance I have no front end and must supply the raw dataset with the already formatted 2 digit string.

Answer (score 62):

```
select right ('00'+ltrim(str( <number> )),2 )
```

Comment: I appreciate how smart this trick it and how it works in a really old systems that lack `format` function.

Answer (score 37):

You can use T-SQL's built in format function:

```
declare @number int  = 1
select format (@number, '0#')
```

Comment: That is only for SQL Server 2012+

Answer (score 20):

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(sortexport_csv AS VARCHAR), 2)
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Luke,  This was the one I was looking for. Simple and Consistent use of CAST. Thank You

Answer (score 10):

You're all doing too much work:

```
right(str(100+@x),2)

-- for a function, same idea: 
--
create function zeroPad( @yourNum int, @wid int)
as 
begin
  return right( 1000000+@yourNum), @wid)
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Convert the value to a string, add a zero in front of it (so that it's two or tree characters), and get the last to characters:

```
right('0'+convert(varchar(2),Sort_Export_CSV),2)
```

Comment: Guffa... I had abandoned convert some time ago but, tis works perfectly. Thank you ALL for your responses. I am overwhelmed:)

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @Number int = 1;
SELECT RIGHT('0'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Number), 2)
--OR
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, 100 + @Number), 2)
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this

```
SELECT RIGHT( '0' + convert( varchar(2) , '0' ),  2 ) -- OUTPUTS : 00
SELECT RIGHT( '0' + convert( varchar(2) , '8' ),  2 ) -- OUTPUTS : 08
SELECT RIGHT( '0' + convert( varchar(2) , '9' ),  2 ) -- OUTPUTS : 09
SELECT RIGHT( '0' + convert( varchar(2) , '10' ), 2 ) -- OUTPUTS : 10
SELECT RIGHT( '0' + convert( varchar(2) , '11' ), 2 ) -- OUTPUTS : 11
```

this should help

Answer (score 2):

Here is tiny function that left pad value with a given padding char
You can specify how many characters to be padded to left..

```
   Create    function fsPadLeft(@var varchar(200),@padChar char(1)='0',@len int)
      returns varchar(300)
    as
    Begin
      return replicate(@PadChar,@len-Len(@var))+@var
    end
```

To call :

```
declare @value int; set @value =2
select dbo.fsPadLeft(@value,'0',2)
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
select RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 2) + CAST(2 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

should return 02

Comment: Whils its nice to use the REPLICATE function, its a bit overboard when a simple '00' will do

Comment: But it's much nicer to maintain

Comment: You don't have to use REPLICATE at all. The single character string '0' will do just fine.

Comment: agreed, my bad, I just used it as a sample.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
right('0' + convert(varchar(2), @number),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
select 
case when teamId < 10 then '0' + cast(teamId as char(1)) 
else cast(teamId as char(2)) end      
as 'pretty id',
* from team
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

--Generate number from 2 to 90

```
;with numcte as(
select 2 as rn
union all
select rn+1 from numcte where rn<90)
```

**--Program that formats the number based on length**

```
select case when LEN(rn) = 1 then '00'+CAST(rn as varchar(10)) else CAST(rn as varchar(10)) end number
from numcte
```

**Partial Output:**

```
number    
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
replace(str(month(DATEADD(month, -1, '2012-02-29')), 2),' ' , '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_convert_int_to_2_digits](@input int)
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    --return value
    DECLARE @return varchar(10)

    if @input < 10
    begin
    set @return = '0' + convert(varchar(1), @valor)
end
    else
    begin
        set @return = convert(varchar(10), @input)
    end

    -- return result
    RETURN @return

END
```

and then use it everywhere:
`select [dbo].[f_convert_int_to_2_digits](<some int>)`

Answer (score 0):

Example for converting one digit number to two digit by adding 0 :

```
DECLARE @int INT = 9 
        SELECT CASE WHEN @int < 10
                    THEN FORMAT(CAST(@int AS INT),'0#')
               ELSE 
                   FORMAT(CAST(@int AS INT),'0')
               END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Number int = 1;
SELECT RIGHT('0'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Number), 2)
--OR
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, 100 + @Number), 2)
GO
```

Comment: some verbal explanation can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
declare
    @len int = 10,
    @number int = 122222,
    @prefix char = '0'

select replicate(@prefix, @len - len(@number)) + CAST(@number AS VARCHAR)
```

result:

> 0000122222