# How to append 0 to a value in SQL Server if value is 1 character using Padding function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting, format

I have a stored procedure that returns YYYYMMDD formatted string.

I'm looking for the right way to create a string of MM and DD if the string supplied has only 1 character.

For example:

If day provided is 1, it needs to be changed to 01 and the same for the month.

```
declare @day as int
declare @month as int

select @day = 1
select @month = 9

Formatting code

select @day   // gives 01
select @month // gives 09
```

I do not want to use `if` logic here to check the length. Is that possible to use some kind of `Formatting` functionality to achieve the same result?

I have found something like:

`select right('0' + cast(@day as varchar(2)),2)`

Would that be the correct solution?

Comment: usually text function are specify to rdbms, what is yours? sqlserver, oracle, mysql?

Comment: try this link if it helps it has many options for same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza `TSQL` tag => `SQL Server`

Comment: Tons of options shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914682/t-sql-format-integer-to-2-digit-string

Comment: What you have with the `right` function is a good solution and imo cleaner than using IF/CASE statements.

Comment: @lad2025 the `TSQL` tag itself mentions that `TSQL` also works in `Sybase`, so it's not true that `TSQL`=>`SQL Server`. However, TSQL's syntax should remain the same across both platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following.  I know that you said you don't want to use an *IF* statement, and I'm probably splitting hairs by supplying a *CASE* statement, but it is an alternative to *IF*:

```
declare @day as int
declare @month as int

select @day = 1
select @month = 9

Formatting code

select CASE WHEN LEN(@day) = 1 THEN '0' + @day ELSE @day END   // gives 01
select CASE WHEN LEN(@month) = 1 THEN '0' + @month ELSE @month END // gives 09
```

You could also try:

```
declare @day as int
declare @month as int

select @day = 1
select @month = 9

Formatting code

select RIGHT('0'+cast(@day AS varchar(2)), 2)  // gives 01
select RIGHT('0'+cast(@day AS varchar(2)), 2) // gives 09
```

Comment: Looks like you've already found the RIGHT() solution.  I guess I should have read a bit further past your posted code before providing the alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

> Would that be the correct solution?

Does it give you the results you want?  Then yes it is *one* solution.  There's nothing *wrong* with it.

I will say a stored procedure seems like an odd choice for this function.  Stored procedures are usually used to return *sets*.  A [scalar function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499.aspx) may be a better choice.